# combine not css selector with adjacent selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to merge these into one

```
input:not([type="checkbox"]) and input td.text-left
```

I did this

`input td.text-left:not([type="checkbox"])`

Why it doesn't work? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing it you are applying the `not` to the `TD` element instead of the `input`.

If your `td` is adjacent to the `input`, then do it like this ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)):

```
input:not([type="checkbox"]) + td.text-left {
    ...
}
```

However, I do not see a situation where an `input` would be adjacent to a `td` element. Can you post more of your HTML?

Comment: The fact that the OP accepted your answer as it is suggests that their markup is exactly what you think it is: non-conforming.

Answer (score 1):

I believe td tag cannot be inside the input tag. Hope the following works for you:

```css
td.text-left input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="text-left">
            <input type="checkbox">
            <input type="text">    
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```